# Legacy exchange MAPI help?

Tags: winapi, exchange-server, mapi

I'm working with some legacy exchange code and I am having trouble finding information about some methods/constants. A google search reveals others using similar code, but with no explanations. Does anyone have any ideas where I can find proper docs? One constant I am looking for is: SYNC_ASSOCIATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange is a Microsoft protocol, so the best place to look is usually MSDN.

The MSDN library, however, seems curiously lacking on Exchange documentation, but [an MSDN search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/?Query=SYNC_ASSOCIATED) looks in a few other places too.

In this case, it's led me to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/exchangedev/archive/2008/03/27/incremental-change-synchronization-api-definitions.aspx) which gives you a number of constants as they would be defined in a C header file. `SYNC_ASSOCIATED` is defined as `0x10`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been able to find the definitions as well, I was just hoping for some explanations as to what each is :)

Comment: There might be more detailed information if you find documentation for the specific methods that use them. I suggest looking at MSDN even though I couldn't find a reference to that definition - I'm not familiar with that API myself, so I don't really know what context you'd use it in, and therefore can't apply my search fu skills very well.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of ICS, Exchange's mechanism for monitoring and tracking changes in a mailbox.  See the [ICS section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219518(EXCHG.80).aspx) of the [bulk data transfer protocol spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463916(EXCHG.80).aspx).